# What is correct approach to maintain resolv.conf on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, dns, centos, networkmanager, resolv.conf

On Ubuntu I use the resolvconf utility to update & maintain /etc/resolv.conf

On CentOS 7, the resolvconf utility doesn't appear to exist.

What is the correct way to maintain /etc/resolv.conf file on CentOS 7 ?

KR,
Nath

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf might cointain some tips.

Comment: The correct way depends of your environment. I have an environment where all servers receive DNS settings through DHCP.

Comment: You may try to use openresolv (http://roy.marples.name/projects/openresolv/index) compiling it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, they all helped me find the solution. Thanks Hannu - using nmcli con edit , then set ipv4.dns allowed me use NetworkManager to update resolv.conf. Zina - I was receiving a default nameserver from my DHCP client and NetworkManager automatically adds it to the top. Cheers guys!